# Efficient way to have an Array from differing variable type

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, ecmascript-6

It's not really a problem, but I like to improve my JavaScript/ES6 skills.

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to always have an array, no matter if my incoming variable has just a single value or an array.

What I'm currently doing is:

```js
var inp;

// just for the showcase
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  inp = 'foo';
} else {
  inp = ['foo', 'bar'];
}

// this is what I want to optimize
if (Array.isArray(inp)) {
  outp = inp;
} else {
  outp = [inp];
}

console.log(outp);
```

I'm *not* talking just shortening the code at any price, but effiency and maybe elegance.

Comment: [The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Leave it how it is and do something more productive with your time :)

Comment: @Liam I like your thinking and Knuths quote has a lot of truth in it.

Comment: @Andy maybe you overread my last sentence...

Comment: Here's another quote for you: [*Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler). In the face of marginal performance gains always pick the option that's the easiest to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about testing it? Here is a jsperf for you: https://jsperf.com/dynamic-array-creation

[image]

`instanceof` seems to be the most efficient way.

Comment: Test first optimise later. that said even the slowest can do 7 millions ops a second....You need to ask yourself if that performance gain is really worth it

Comment: Deliberately choosing a solution that is 20x slower is a bad practice. Non optimal code adds up and slows down the performance significantly on slower devices and increases power consumption. Also, if your solution is used by millions of users, that becomes even more important.

Comment: Is this solution used by *millions of users*? Is this a bottle neck or can you can more bang for your buck somewhere else, like I said [*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998840/efficient-way-to-have-an-array-from-differing-variable-type/49999061?noredirect=1#comment87013770_49998840)

Comment: Testing is the correct answer though. Everything else is a guess at best

Comment: You could use that argument, if you did not know the consequences. But now you do. So if you know and still use the non optimal code, that’s unethical.

Comment: Ethics are subjective. [Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler).

Comment: As the original question was about "efficiency", performance test is an objective way to evaluate the alternatives.

Comment: I agree with @jancha who created the IMO most complete answer regarding efficiency and will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You can skip this `isArray` check with using `concat`:

```
const outp = [].concat(inp);
```

It'll always give you an array with elements (not nested):

```
[].concat('foo')
// ['foo']

[].concat(['foo'])
// ['foo']
```

Comment: Elegant solution

Comment: If you really badly need to shave off that one line of code, this is the way I guess. Personally I think it might be a bit unintuitive because it's not immediately apparent what this code is supposed to accomplish and why it's even there, which may make it difficult for an outside viewer (or yourself, a few weeks later) to understand. Still, upvoted because it works and does what OP needs :)

Comment: This appears to be [**less** efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999061/542251) and I'd argue is [harder to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998840/efficient-way-to-have-an-array-from-differing-variable-type#comment87014719_49998840).

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches are possible. Depending on how accurate you wan't you detection to be. A quick example:

```
var outp = Array.isArray(inp) ? inp : in[];
```

Which is nothing more than a shorthand for your code.

You should ask yourself if this is desirable. If you have function that expects an array but gets a string as input. Should it even continue? Many interfaces provide different explicit methods for this. E.g.: `add(array)` and `addOne(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` empty array `[]` if `Math.random` is less than `0.5`

```
["foo"].concat( Math.random > 0.5 ? "bar" : [] )
```